# Thunderbird: No progress while indexing IMAP folder

Tags: ubuntu, thunderbird, imap

I think my thunderbird is in an useless endless loop.

It happens repeatable.

Output of strace -p PID:

```
recvmsg(4, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\34\0\253\30)\1 \2\375\1\0\0\4\22\22\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 4096}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 32
recvmsg(4, 0x7ffea5151530, 0)           = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(4, 0x7ffea5151510, 0)           = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=5, events=POLLIN}, {fd=11, events=POLLIN}, {fd=28, events=POLLIN}, {fd=29, events=POLLIN}, {fd=358, events=POLLIN}], 6, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
recvmsg(4, 0x7ffea5151510, 0)           = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=5, events=POLLIN}, {fd=11, events=POLLIN}, {fd=28, events=POLLIN}, {fd=29, events=POLLIN}, {fd=358, events=POLLIN}], 6, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
recvmsg(4, 0x7ffea5151510, 0)           = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=5, events=POLLIN}, {fd=11, events=POLLIN}, {fd=28, events=POLLIN}, {fd=29, events=POLLIN}, {fd=358, events=POLLIN}], 6, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
recvmsg(4, 0x7ffea5151510, 0)           = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=5, events=POLLIN}, {fd=11, events=POLLIN}, {fd=28, events=POLLIN}, {fd=29, events=POLLIN}, {fd=358, events=POLLIN}], 6, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
recvmsg(4, 0x7ffea5151510, 0)           = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=5, events=POLLIN}, {fd=11, events=POLLIN}, {fd=28, events=POLLIN}, {fd=29, events=POLLIN}, {fd=358, events=POLLIN}], 6, -1) = 1 ([{fd=29, revents=POLLIN}])
```

With `top` I can see that thunderbird is the only process which needs CPU. It needs 30% cpu.

With `iotop` I see that nearly no io gets done.

Even several minutes later. The strace output of the thunderbird process is the same.

In the activity list of thunderbird I see that it tries to scan images in a IMAP folder.

With `dmesg` I see no errors. The filesystems seems to be ok.

The thunderbird process has a lot of open files:

```
ls -ltr /proc/2797/fd| wc -l
116
```

Most of the files are .msf files.

Thunderbird reacts very slow. The GUI is almost unusable.

What's going on here? What can I do?

Running  Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Here is the activity list. Yesterday thunderbird was hanging here for several hours. After rebooting it is the same again:

[image]

File descriptor 4 is a unix domain socket:

```
root@ThinkPad-E520:~# ls -ltr /proc/3059/fd| grep ' 4 '
lrwx------ 1 guettli guettli 64 Aug 14 06:14 4 -> socket:[32096]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend told me that Thunderbird sometimes breaks its database files.

I removed my ~/.thunderbird folder and started thunderbird. Then I added my IMAP accounts and now everything is working again.

I lost all my custom thunderbird settings on this PC, but I had only very few of them.